# iOS WatchOS5 - how do I determine the size of the WatchOS complication from the phone?

Tags: ios, apple-watch-complication, watchos-5

I'm looking at [this video on developing complications for the apple watch](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/208/) and [this size chart of watch complication sizes](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/watchos/icons-and-images/complication-images/).

Currently I have my phone generate a full screen complication image on the phone and push it to the watch using background app refresh. However, I don't know how to get the correct device complication size.

The documentation suggests that I can programmatically load an image from a watch asset catalog on the watch and it will load the correct size image based on device size. I can then examine this image and determine the size. However, this would require a round trip and sending the size to the phone using WKSession.

**Is there an easy way to determine ON THE PHONE what is the screen size of the apple watch?** I see code that is supposed to run on the watch, but my app generates assets on the phone.

```
//complication - smaller devices
let width = 300.0
let height = 94.0

//complication - larger devices            
let width = 342.0
let height = 108.0
```

I may be able to scale the image down by 1.14 on smaller devices, but that would make the image more blurry.